# How to identify when a specific portion of content is visible and when not on the screen of an app running on a cell phone using JS?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, user-interface

There is one advertisement that is displayed on the screen of an app running on a cell phone(not in a web browser) along with some other content. The advertisement is present in one `<div>` tag having `id="adv"`

As user scrolls down or up, the advertisement gets invisible and visible. I want a jQuery/JavaScript code to identify when the advertisement(or you can say `<div id="adv"></div>`) is visible on the screen and when not depending on the scroll action of user.

If the advertisement is visible I'll trigger some event and when the ad is not visible I'll call some other event.

In other words I want the visible state of the advertisement. This has to be done using JS.

Please help me someone in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice obvious thing - calculate some "client height", but not sure how exactly that works, if it's possible this should be the best sollution.

As a second variant, probably not as efficient, I can suggest you to make a wrapper around the "desired screen" and catch hover event. The code will be something like this:

```
document.getElemenentById('yourWrapper').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  /* Your handler here */
});
```